# When should I consider to use pretrain-model word2vec model weights?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, pre-trained-model

Suppose my corpus is reasonably large - having tens-of-thousands of unique words. I can either use it to build a word2vec model directly(Approach #1 in the code below) or initialize a new word2vec model with pre-trained model weights and fine tune it with my own corpus(Approach #2). Is the approach #2 worth consideration? If so, is there a rule of thumb on when I should consider a pre-trained model?

```
# Approach #1
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(my_corpus, vector_size=300, min_count=1)

# Approach #2
model = Word2Vec(vector_size=300, min_count=1)
model.build_vocab(my_corpus)
model.intersect_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True, lockf=1.0)
model.train(my_corpus, total_examples=len(my_corpus))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to this type of question is: you should try them both, and see which works better for your purposes.

No one without your exact data & project goals can be sure which will work better in your situation, and you'll need to exact same kind of ability-to-evaluate alterante choices to do all sorts of very basic, necessary tuning of your work.

Separately:

- "fine-tuning" word2vec-vectors can mean many things, and can introduce a number of expert-leve thorny tradeoff-decisions - the sorts of tradeoffs that can only be navigated if you've got a robust way to test different choices against each other.
- The specific simple tuning approach your code shows - which relies on an experimental method (`intersect_word2vec_format()`) that might not work in the latest Gensim – is pretty limited, and since it discards all the words in the outside vectors that aren't already in your own corpus, also discards one of the major reasons people often want to mix older vectors in - to cover more words not in their training data. (I doubt that approach will be useful in many cases, but as per above, to be sure you'd want to try it with respect to your data/goals.
- It's almost always a bad idea to use `min_count=1` with word2vec & similar algorithms. If such rare words are truly important, find more training examples so good vectors can be trained for them. But without enough training examples, they're usually better to ignore - keeping them even makes the vectors for surrounding words worse.

Comment: "since it discards all the words in the outside vectors that aren't already in your own corpus, also discards one of the major reasons people often want to mix older vectors in - to cover more words not in their training data." Can you elaborate on what you mean by "outside vectors" and "older vectors"?

Comment: Imagine you have a corpus with 10k unique words. You then use the code above to import those 10k words, where they exist, from the 3 million word `GoogleNews` vectors. Then, you train a bunch on your corpus. At the end, you've only got those 10k word-vectors in your model, and they've been trained – pulled to new coordinates! – based only on the text of your corpus. And at the end, your model only has 10k vectors in it.

Comment: Do you just need those 10k words? If so, all's well, but then using the `GoogleNews` starting vectors for some of your words may not have helped much. Were you intending to then compare those 10k words with the other 2.99M-plus back in the other set? That might not work well, because depending on how much training you've done, they've been pulled out of sure-fire alignment with the "older" vectors. There's a murky tradeoff: the more you train on the new text, the better your words will fit your new texts - but they could be arbitrarily further from comparability with the original vectors.

Comment: That's why I wouldn't recommend an approach like this unless you have a strong idea of why it'll improve on other options, for example from a well-documented example of how it could help & all the difficult tradeoffs to monitor/adjust.