# For Gensim 4.0, how to use a pre-trained model and further train it with my own corpus?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, pre-trained-model

For Gensim 3.8, I can use the following script to initialize a model with pre-train weights and then train it on my own corpus. How to do this in Gensim 4.0?

```
mod = Word2Vec(size=300, min_count=5, workers=1, sg=1, seed=1)
mod.build_vocab(my_corpus)
mod.min_count = 0
pret_mod = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True)
mod.build_vocab([list(pret_mod.vocab.keys())], update=True)
mod.intersect_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True, lockf=1.0)
mod.train(my_corpus, total_examples=mod.corpus_count, epochs=mod.iter)
```

Comment: Why do you think such a process is a good idea? (What person or web page recommended this approach, and why do you prefer it over just training on your own text?)

Comment: @gojomo Do you mean we either find enough corpus to train our own word2vec model or just use a pre-trained model as it is? I got the inspiration from transfer learning and fine-tuning and saw some people are using this approach online.

Comment: Who are "some people" - what persons or web pages provide evidence that this is worth the extra complication? Are they credible? If they have a good case, might they be able to update their code & explanation for Gensim 4.0+? Do they demonstrate that this approach has better results than the more simple option of just training on your own data? (As I'd mentioned in a prior answer – https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099950/130288 – this approach, by throwing away all the words i `GoogleNews` not also in the local data, also discards most of the motivation for using 'fine-tuning' techniques.)